# Flutter DropDown Container under TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have like a DropDown Container under a `TextField` in Flutter.
As you see, in the code, if there is a difference in `widget._searchListfinal` and `widget._searchListtmp`, the DropDown should be reloaded.
When the first value of `_searchListtmp` is ready, it should open the DropDown.
When the user clicks outside of the TextField, the DropDown should be closed.
In further steps, there should be a table and the user can select an entry.

Problem is by now, that the AlertDialog is not due to my needs, because it always opens in the center of the screen instead of under the TextField.

This is my code:

```
return ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.search),
  title: TextField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      onChanged: (String value) {
        widget._searchListtmp = value.split(RegExp(r'\s+')).where((element) => element.length >= 3).toList();
        if (widget._searchListfinal != widget._searchListtmp) {
          widget._searchListfinal = widget._searchListtmp;
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                  content: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    color: const Color(0xFFFFFF),
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Text(widget._searchListfinal.join('&'))
                  )
                )
              );
            }
          ) ;
        }
      },
  ),
  trailing: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
        //do stuff
        });
      }
  )
);
```

Comment: I think you are looking for auto_complete solution, for that you can check `flutter_typeahead`